# Получение значений с стороннего сайта

Tags: android

Как можно получить значение с сайта допустим и передать его в android

допустим  с этого сайта получить число(120 296) подписчиков и запихать в переменную int a; 
[Этот как пример взял](https://www.change.org/p/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9)

и допустим при обновлении что бы оно изменялось на новое(которое будет на сайте)

:)простите что по тупому обьясняю, но направьте меня на правильный путь:)

Comment: Тебе необходимо изучить темы: - Парсеры html/xml - Отправка/получение данных в/из интернет По второму пункту инфы очень много, по первому можно сначала поискать парсеры на чистую Java, они полностью работают на android

Comment: Я так даже сделал бота для одной браузерной онлайн игры через библиотеку JSOUP( https://jsoup.org/ ). Обновлять можно таймером например создав Service

Comment: а что бы передавать значения это уже нужно API сайта?

Comment: Передаются значения обычно на сервер, тебе придётся или эмулировать создание запроса "как на сайте", или действительно получить доступ к API

Comment: А через HTTP POST нельзя ?

допустим такой пример: на сайте кнопка и текст = (количество нажатий)

мне нужно передать количество нажатий в android, и в андройде при нажатии на button повышать это количество на сайте. :)( к примеру через POST)
Так можно сделать?
или как лучше делать

Comment: Скорее всего, на сайте при нажатии кнопки будет отправляться запрос на сервер о том, что произошло нажатие, с помощью Ajax, тебе же будет достаточно с клиента просто отправлять этот запрос на сервер